# Merge Sort in Python - RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, mergesort

I am working on merge sort in Python.

I have checked `merge` function. The arrays are merging fine.

But in the `mergeSort` Function an error is coming :---

> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.
>
> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        63     print(arr[i]),
>        64 
>   ---> 65 mergeSort(arr,0,n-1)
>        66 print(" ")
>        67 print("Sorted Array is")
>
> in mergeSort(arr, l, r)
>        53         m = l+(r-1)/2
>        54         mergeSort(arr,l,m)
>   ---> 55         mergeSort(arr,m+1,r)
>        56         merge(arr,l,m,r)
>        57

What can be the possible cause of this?

```
def merge(arr,l,m,r):
    n1 = m-l+1
    n2 = r-m

    L = [0] * n1
    R = [0] * n2

    print("First List")
    for i in range(0,n1):
        L[i] = arr[i+l]
        print(L[i]), 


    print("")
    print("Second List")    
    for j in range(0,n2):
        R[j] = arr[j+m+1]
        print(R[j]),



    #Merging the temp arrays
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    print("")
    print("Merged List ---------->")

    while i < n1 and j < n2:
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            arr[k] = L[i]
            print(arr[k]),
            i+=1
        else:
            arr[k] = R[j]
            print(arr[k]),
            j+=1
        k+=1

    while i<n1:
        arr[k] = L[i]
        i+=1
        k+=1

    while j<n2:
        arr[k] = R[j]
        print(arr[k])
        j+=1
        k+=1

def mergeSort(arr,l,r):
    if l<r:
        m = l+(r-1)/2
        mergeSort(arr,l,m)
        mergeSort(arr,m+1,r)
        merge(arr,l,m,r)


arr = [0,12,13,0,1,22]
n = len(arr)

mergeSort(arr,0,n-1)
print(" ")
print("Sorted Array is")
for i in range(0,n-1):
    print(arr[i])
```

Answer (score 3):

The way `m` is calculated in `mergeSort` is wrong(you need to divide in half the whole expression, not only `(r-1)`). Change it to:

```
m = (l+(r-1))/2
```

As you were calculating that incorrectly your method was calling itself recursively over and over again until the maximum method stack depth was exceeded and thus crashing.

Answer (score 2):

- You did the basic mistake .Python is dynamically type language
- Before going to why you got that Run Time RecurssionError ,you need to make one change.
  Instead of  `m = l+(r-1)/2`  write `m = (l+r)/2`
  Because when you called `mergeSort(arr,0,n-1)` at that time `n-1` is last index value and that's why there is no need of `r-1` in `m = l+(r-1)/2`

### Floor Division operator(//) VS Normal division operator(/)

Now coming to the main point why did you got that **RecurssionError** here is the answer

- When you are doing operation like

> m = (l+r)/2

Divide operation will give **fractional** part i.e. `m` will be treated as floating variable
so `m` would never be **0** it would be any floating number say something **0.123** or **2.122** or **1.0025**

Because of floating point as `m` would never be **0** the if condition `if l<r:` would always true and the ***mergeSort()*** function goes into **Infinite loop** and that's why you got that RunTime RecurssionERROR

> You want **m** as ***integer*** and not ***float*** so instead of m=(l+r)/2
>
> Write **m=(l+r)//2**  the ***floor division operator(//)*** will give you integer value and your **mergeSort()** function will not go under Infinite Loop

**Your code will get executed this time without any Error just make one change *m=(l+r)//2***

**BUT BUT BUT your merge() function algo is not good it does not give sorted array also the data is lost and something else gets printed**

Answer (score -1):

Its because when you are calling mergesort function, you are passing l = 0 and r= lenght of list. 
And no matter what your calculation going to be in every case you l will be less than r.

```
 m = l+(r-1)/2
```